# Trying to install a Kafka Connect connector via a jar file using Docker, installation gives errors

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have am using docker-compose along with a Dockerfile to install a connector. I have been successful in installing connectors from Confluent Hub, but not my own jar files.

Here is what I did:

1. Went to https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.aiven/aiven-kafka-connect-gcs/0.7.0/jar and in the upper right corner, pressed Downloads and clicked on "jar"
2. Placed this file in the same folder as my Dockerfile
3. Ran my Dockerfile:

```
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"

USER root
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser aiven-kafka-connect-gcs-0.7.0.jar /usr/share/confluent-hub-components
USER appuser

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt aiven/kafka-connect-gcs:0.7.0
```

I have also tried various `confluent-hub install` commands, including:

```
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt aiven-kafka-connect-gcs:0.7.0
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluent-hub-components/aiven-kafka-connect-gcs-0.7.0.jar
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt aiven-kafka-connect-gcs-0.7.0.jar
```

all to no avail. I did try other directories like `/etc/kafka-connect/jars` and I just keep getting the same issue.

What am I doing wrong? Syntax? Missing additional mounting commands? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
RUN wget -O /set/your/path/here/<connector name here>.tar https://url-of-connector-here/<connector name and version here>.tar
RUN tar -xvf /set/your/path/here/<connector name here>.tar --directory /path/to/connect/plugins/here/
```

and it worked.

Comment: This is exactly what confluent hub cli does, too. I thought you're trying to download a jar, not a tar?

Comment: I was unsure if it had to be a jar or a tar file. I thought I could use a jar file in this manner, but I need to use a zip/tar/etc file in this way.

Answer (score 0):

`confluent-hub` doesn't "install" local JAR files

By default, it uses its arguments to do an HTTP lookup against the Confluent Hub website and return the according response. If it's a valid connector, it'll extract it to the plugin path, otherwise, you'll get an error

If you give it a local ZIP, that will work

> path to a local ZIP file that was downloaded from Confluent Hub

Comment: The documentation says otherwise. There are many videos of others installing jar or zip files using this same command. I'm just having a hard time with it

Comment: There's no reason to install local files. You just extract or move their files with regular shell commands